# tensorflowのplaceholder エラーが解決しない

Tags: python, tensorflow, 深層学習

Deep Learningの勉強をしています。
参考書籍に書かれた通り、pythonでコーディングし、jupyter notebookで実行したところ、
以下のエラーが発生しました。
エラーの発生原因がわからず、どなたかエラー原因をご指摘いただけると幸いです。

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,784]
     [[node Placeholder (defined at <ipython-input-1-fbb51774c0a2>:9)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

以下、本に書かれていたコードです。

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

#mnistデータを格納したオブジェクトを呼び出す
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("data/", one_hot=True)

#入力データを定義
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#入力画像をログに出力
img = tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1])
tf.summary.image("input_data", img, 10)

#入力層から中間層
with tf.name_scope("hidden"):
    w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 64], stddev=0.1), name="w1")
    b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]), name="b1")
    h_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w_1) + b_1)

    #中間層の重みの分布をログ出力
    tf.summary.histogram('w_1',w_1)

#中間層から出力層
with tf.name_scope("output"):
    w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([64, 10], stddev=0.1), name="w2")
    b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="b2")
    out = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_1, w_2) + b_2)

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

#誤差関数
with tf.name_scope("loss"):    
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - out))

    #誤差をログ出力
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)

#訓練
with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

#評価
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(out,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

    #精度をログ出力
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

#初期化
init =tf.global_variables_initializer()

summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs", sess.graph)

    sess.run(init)    

    #テストデータをロード    
    test_images = mnist.test.images    
    test_labels = mnist.test.labels    

    for step in range(1000):        
        train_images, train_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:train_images ,y:train_labels})

        if step % 10 == 0:
            #ログを取る処理を実行する（出力はログ情報が書かれたプロトコルバッファ）
            summary_str = sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict={x:test_images, y:test_labels})
            #ログ情報のプロトコルバッファを書き込む
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
```

参考書籍：TensorFlowではじめるDeepLearning実践入門
https://book.impress.co.jp/books/1117101113

Comment: `feed_dict={x:...`で指定しているdataが[?,784]の形になっていない。もしくはfloatの形になっていないというエラーになります。ご提示のコードだけでは判断できませんので、まずはtrain_imagesやtest_imagesをログにだして[?,784]のfloatになっているか確認しては如何でしょうか。