# tensorflowのplaceholderに渡したもののshapeが違うと怒られる

Tags: python, tensorflow

MNIST手書き文字認識を2層のNNでやってみました
コードはこちらになります[gist](https://gist.github.com/naoppy/d5e74476ce4d44b399c09184b5a7e46a)
12Cell目のif内でsummary_opを実行するとエラーで落ちます。
エラー内容はx(name=input_x)のshapeがおかしい？ということのようですが、そんなはずはなく、悩んでいます。
しかも、カーネルを再起動して動かすと一回目の実行はエラーを吐かずにうまく行きますが、2回目の実行(Run All)から必ずそこでエラーで落ちます。

環境ですが、tensorflow1.12.0, python3.6.8, ipython7.3.0, conda4.5.12となります。

[恐らく同様のエラーと思われる質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51044/tensorflow%E3%81%AEplaceholder-%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)があったのですが、解決していないようなので質問させていただきました。

Comment: notebookを.pyに変換して実行したところ、普通に動きました。どうやらjupyter notebookのカーネルのキャッシュかなにかが悪さをしているようです。解決方法としてはRestart & run allを毎回すればいいと思います。ただ、どういうキャッシュが...というところまではわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

tf.summary は全然わからないのですが、計算グラフを作っているセルを複数回実行すると、

```
tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
```

などで、同じようなグラフが複数作られ、それを全部まとめている

```
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

ので、混乱しているものと思われます。計算グラフを作り始める前にグラフをリセットするようにしたら、このセルを複数回実行しても大丈夫になりました。

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# 入力層 ニューロン数28*28=784, 行数可変
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name="input_x")
```